# Best method for building a Database repository for keeping data coming from different sources with varying columns

Tags: mysql, sql, database, normalization, data-warehouse

i have to build a common database for storing patient related data for a particular disease collected from various parts of the country in different formats.

All the files are collecting in csv format which may contain different column values.

I am totally confused in organizing the data, whether to follow normalized method or denormalized method.

I am planning to do it in following way

1. importing all the tables got till now in to seperate db as individual tables.
2. Designing and creating a database with normalized tables and EAV tables and migrating the data to it manually
3. Creating a third warehouse database with denormalised tables from second one for easy querying.

Kindly suggest any good alternate method to solve my requirement.

[I found an article about this](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2110957/)

Comment: What sort of queries do you plan to use on this data?

Comment: select with grouping, sub queries like that

Comment: If you have varying data structures, how about importing / storing the data in a `JSON` field and then categorizing each record as a `record_type` (i.e. "patient record - Sharp Health").  You could then write a function / stored procedure that would manipulate / return the data as needed based on the `record_type`.

Comment: until a pattern emerges, I'd just put each to their own table. As its static data, start to create summary tables as things become re-used. Going full normalized or denomalised from the start will just be effort for not much reward. EAV will just make hard queries to write.

Comment: Ultimately i need to combine all the sources as one table where all sources have some common data for querying along with their on specific items

Comment: Do you need to hold History, or holding just the last stand is enough?

Comment: @momobo both required

Comment: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2110957/